# How to fix "java.sql.SQLException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true"

Tags: java, mysql, sql, exception

I am working on java and mysql and I couldn't fix the errors. I am facing these errors when I insert new farmer to the table...

> java.sql.SQLException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true

Errors are below

> java.sql.SQLException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true
>
> at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:869)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:865)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.commit(ConnectionImpl.java:1537)
>   at client.Main.addonething(Main.java:784)
>           at client.Main.parse_commands(Main.java:123)
>           at client.Main.main_loop(Main.java:202)
>           at client.Main.main(Main.java:239)
>       com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Can't call rollback when autocommit=true
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:4560)
>           at client.Main.addonething(Main.java:795)
>           at client.Main.parse_commands(Main.java:123)
>           at client.Main.main_loop(Main.java:202)
>           at client.Main.main(Main.java:239)

This is the database connection code

```
 public static void addonething(String query, DBConnection dbConnection){
        Statement myStmt;
        try {
            myStmt =  dbConnection.getConn().createStatement();
            int swichA = 0;
            int swichB = 0;
            myStmt.execute(query);

    System.out.println("To commit the data enter 1");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    swichB = in.nextInt();
    if(swichA != -1 && swichB == 1){
        System.out.println();
        dbConnection.getConn().commit();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("it came hear3");
        dbConnection.getConn().rollback();
    }

} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("it came hear4");
    e.printStackTrace();
    try {
        dbConnection.getConn().rollback();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        System.out.println("it came hear5");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Below is the insert method

```
public static String frQuery(String second_part){
    String data = get_data_from_commands(second_part);
    String[] tokens = data.split(",");
    String queryf = String.format("insert into farmers" + " 
            (Name, lastname, Address, zipcode, city, phones, mails)" + "values 
      ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",tokens[0],tokens[1],tokens[2], 
       tokens[3],tokens[4],tokens[5], tokens[6]);

    return queryf;
}
```

Comment: Turn AutoCommit off.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable auto commit by using this code:

```
 //Note : This will implicitly commit the active transaction and create a new one
 connection.setAutoCommit(false);
```

Now the set of statements ( transaction ) will be  committed on :

```
connection.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically when we write query and execute them defaultly they will commit it resist it we have to specify don't commit and commit only when I specify.

that is we can do it by like

```java
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
con.setAutoCommit(false);
```

This will set the autocommit not to commit automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-commit mode means that when a statement is completed, the method commit is called on that statement automatically. When auto-commit is enabled, any changes made to the database will be committed "immediately" after the statement is executed.

In case of Transaction on a method, it will override the auto-commit setting for that method(if auto-commit is on default mode). This means Transaction will `set auto-commit false` and queries executed within the method will be part of the same transaction. Basically, the framework will take care to configure the necessary auto-commit value.

**But When you explicitly set auto-commit to true**, you are telling Hibernate that you want to control when transactions are committed. And in this case, if needs to use the @Transacional method then you have to set auto-commit=false manually before using the transaction otherwise cause an exception `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true`